# Converting the polar equation $r\cos2\theta = \frac1r+\cos\theta$ to Cartesian

Tags: polar-coordinates

> Find the Cartesian equation of the polar curve
> $$r\cos2\theta = \frac1r+\cos\theta$$
>
> Options:
>
> 1. $x^2-y^2=1+x$
> 2. $x^2-y^2=1-x$
> 3. $x^2+y^2=1+x$
> 4. $x^2+y^2=1-x$
> 5. None of the above.

I've solved both sides of the equation separately:

$$r\cos(2\theta) = r\cos^2(\theta) - r\sin^2(\theta) = x^2-y^2 \tag{1}$$

and

$$\frac1r+\cos(\theta) \quad\stackrel{\times r}{\to}\quad 1+r\cos(\theta) = 1+x \tag{2}$$

But I'm not sure if I can just throw the two sides of the equation together and call it a day? I don't think I can since if I multiply one side by $r$ then I must do it to the other side which messes up my answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you write what the question is?

Comment: I just added it at the top but it might not have updated yet - the question is 'find the Cartesian equation of the polar curve rcos2theta = (1/r)+costheta'

Comment: Have you ever heard of parentheses and exponents? If you used them, we could understand what expressions like "rcos2theta" mean.

Comment: I don't know how to add them on here, luckily someone was kind enough to fix that for me.

Comment: *"[I]f I multiply one side by $r$ then I must do it to the other side ..."* ... Correct! ... *"... which messes up my answer."* ... Luckily(?), your answer has a couple of errors. First, $\cos2\theta$ is not equal to $\cos\theta-\sin\theta$. And, even if it were, $r\cos\theta$ would not become $x^2$, nor would $r\sin\theta$ become $y^2$.

Comment: I think I meant cos(2)=cos^2()−sin^2(), however, that's still likely to be incorrect knowing me! @Blue

Comment: @AlexKelly: Ah, you've made a correction. Yes, $\cos2\theta=\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta$. However, $r\cos^2\theta$ still doesn't correspond to $x^2$, nor $r\sin^2\theta$ to $y^2$. ... Try that thing where you multiply the original equation through by $r$ on both sides. :)

Comment: @Blue does r^2*cos^2(theta) become x^2, and r^2*cos^2(theta) become y^2? Sorry for making this really hard to read!

Comment: @AlexKelly: *"does r^2*cos^2(theta) become x^2, and r^2*cos^2(theta) become y^2?"* ... Yes! :)  ... *"Sorry for making this really hard to read!"* ... You'll get better. Take a look at [this MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/409) for tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplication by $r$ is the right way forward, but as @Blue notes$$x^2-y^2=r^2(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)=r^2\cos2\theta,$$so the problem you fear never arises. (Dimensional analysis is a good sanity check for problems like this, as it would have exposed your power miscounting.) So$$0=r^2\cos2\theta-r\cos\theta-1=x^2-y^2-x-1,$$which is option 1. As a geometric aside, this is a hyperbola, $(x-\tfrac12)^2-y^2=\tfrac54$.